# Inheritance or not?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have a product entity and a separate class for display and one to retrieve the data from the DB. My colleague wants to let these classes inherit from each other instead:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The latter is just non-sense. A `Product` is never a `ProductLoader`. And the display of a product is also not a product (or eventually it is some different kind of product). So just go with the first solution.

N.B. from what is currently shown the top right arrow should just be a `Dependency`. Instead of using an attribute you could use a role top left:

[image]